# How to translate title attribute in acl.xml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, localisation, acl

I have this code in `acl.xml`:

```
 <resource id="Magento_Paypal::use" title="Place Order Using Billing Agreements" translate="title" sortOrder="15" />
```

and I already added this string in `ar_SA.csv` like that:

```
     "Place Order Using Billing Agreements","translation here"
```

but the translation doesn't appear yet. Did I miss something?

I've updated the translation file, flushed the cache but it didn't help.

[image: Magento Admin]

Comment: try to remove pub/static folder and run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy xx_XX 
Wher xx_XX your locale.

Answer (score 3):

currently **acl**  in magento does not support translate functionality. Refer acl.xsd. (I an not sure if you should use your custom xsd file or not)

> Magento 2 default acl.xsd snippet

only these four attributes are available:

```
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="typeId" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="module" type="typeModule" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="title" type="typeTitle" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="sortOrder" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
```

Comment: So how I can translate
magento roles resources https://image.ibb.co/iGXyGF/rol.jpg

Comment: Are you sure? The XSD is not necessarily complete. Core files use the "translate" attribute: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/acl.xml#L12

Comment: yes, They might implement in future, but currently I don't think its supported.

Comment: Hi, just seen the acl.xml in Magento2.1.3, looks like they have added the tranlate attibute for acl now. If you are working on older version, I suggest upgrade your magento version.